# how to import frame based external swf file to scrollpane for as3/flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4, pdf2swf

i'm using pdf2swf but i can't import external swf frame per frame in scrollpane like to  scribd (http://www.scribd.com/doc/27241116/BLOOD-GRISTLE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is : http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/